# Problem with HTML (table) to libre office

Tags: libreoffice

If this is the wrong place to ask this question - please point me in the right direction and delete my question.

I have a large table (also containing multiple tables and images), written in Seamonkey (my preferred HTML editor).  I want to transfer it to either a .doc or a pdf without too much hassle.  Firstly putting it into libreoffice write it doesn't copy the complete table, it misses out parts.  So, tried putting it into abiword - but that editor keeps on refusing to save the images, (looks great whilst editing, go to save it, re-open and hey presto all images have gone!).  Can anyone help?

Comment: Currently re-writing whole table in calc - I will be here some time!

Comment: Ah ha, just dropped it all into abiword, re-inserted pics then saved to pdf - that has sort of got me what I want...  but I would still like to know if anyone else has problems like this.

Comment: a loooong time ago i used [Table2Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dafizilla-table2clipboard/)... maybe worth a look.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy.  I'm going to give this a go - many thanks for that - I should have looked at addons to start with!

Comment: Hmm, did you try just opening the html document with the table in libreoffice? It should work.